# React-d3 Line Chart not showing and showing no errors

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-d3

I'm trying to create my first react d3 line chart but I'm running into a snag. There are no errors showing up when I inspect Chrome so I'm not sure why it's not showing up. I feel like I'm close though.

I've tried to look at other examples but I don't find many with csv examples for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import csvData from "../sandbox.csv";

import {
  select,
  line,
  curveCardinal,
  axisBottom,
  axisRight,
  scaleLinear,
} from "d3";

function ActionsLineGraph() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  // const [data, setData] = useState([25, 30, 45, 60, 20, 65, 75]);
  const svgRef = useRef();

  // will be called initially and on every data change
  useEffect(() => {
    d3.csv(csvData).then((data) => {
      // console.log("Fetching Data");
      console.log(data);
      setData(data);
      setLoading(false);

      const svg = select(svgRef.current);

      const xScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, data.length - 1])
        .range([0, 300]);

      const yScale = scaleLinear().domain([0, 150]).range([150, 0]);

      const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale)
        .ticks(data.length)
        .tickFormat((index) => index + 1);
      svg.select(".x-axis").style("transform", "translateY(150px)").call(xAxis);

      const yAxis = axisRight(yScale);
      svg.select(".y-axis").style("transform", "translateX(300px)").call(yAxis);

      // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
      const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 70 },
        width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // add X axis and Y axis
      const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
      const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

      const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

      const myLine = d3.line()
                  .x(d =>  x(xScale(parseTime(d.date))))
                  .y(d => y(yScale(Number(d.added))));

/* const myLine = d3.line()
                  .x((d) => { return x(parseTime(d.date)); })
                  .y((d) => { return y(Number(d.added)); }); */
     
      svg
        .append("path")
        .data([data])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 10)
        .attr("d", myLine)
        .style('overflow', 'visible')
        // .style("transform", "translate(500px, 150px)");
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <svg ref={svgRef}>
        <g className="x-axis" />
        <g className="y-axis" />
      </svg>
      
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default ActionsLineGraph;
```

Here is my csv data I'm using:

```
date,added,updated,deleted
2021-09-15,10,9,8
2021-09-16,20,11,7
2021-09-17,15,12,9
2021-09-18,20,9,8
2021-09-19,20,9,8
```

Currently, it just shows the tips of the axes
[image]

Any and all help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains some errors. See a solution in the snippet:

```js
const csvData = `date,added,updated,deleted
2021-09-15,10,9,8
2021-09-16,20,11,7
2021-09-17,15,12,9
2021-09-18,20,9,8
2021-09-19,20,9,8
`;

const ActionsLineGraph = (props) => {
  const svgRef = React.useRef();

  // will be called initially and on every data change
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const data = d3.csvParse(csvData);
    console.log(data);
    const parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);
    const from = parseTime(data[0].date);
    const to = parseTime(data[data.length-1].date);
    console.log('FROM: ', from);
    console.log('TO: ', to);

    const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([to, from])
        .range([300, 0]);

      const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 30]).range([150, 0]);

      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .ticks(data.length)
        .tickFormat((index) => index + 1);
      svg.select(".x-axis").style("transform", "translateY(150px)").call(xAxis);

      const yAxis = d3.axisRight(yScale);
      svg.select(".y-axis").style("transform", "translateX(300px)").call(yAxis);

      // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
      const margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 70 },
        width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 150 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      // add X axis and Y axis
      const x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
      const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    
      const path = data.reduce((path, item, index) => {
        const x = xScale(parseTime(item.date));
        const y = yScale(Number(item.added));
        const point = `${x},${y}`;
        return index === 0 ? `M ${point}` : `${path} L ${point}`;
      }, null);
      
      console.log('PATH: ', path);

      svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 10)
        .attr("d", path)
  }, [svgRef]);

  return (
      <svg ref={svgRef}>
        <g className="x-axis" />
        <g className="y-axis" />
      </svg>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ActionsLineGraph />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```